# Real time Sound output over USB

Tags: audio, input-device

I want to be able to record my guitar onto my Macbook pro. since my Macbook pro model doesn't have a sound input jack, i want to do it through USB using Raspberry Pi.

Is it possible to create this with Raspberry Pi?

The flow will be as follows

Guitar->Multi Effects Pedal-> **3.5mm Audio jack-> Raspberry PI -> USB** -> Macbook PRO ->GarageBand.

I suppose that there isn't any sound/signal processing involved in the Raspberry PI for this, so it can achieve very minuscule latency.

I can even get into some coding if its required for the device drivers.

Comment: Could you specify the acceptable delay? I guess it needs to be less than a few tens of milliseconds?

Comment: Macbook Pro has no sound input connector? Where this world is going? :(

Comment: The Raspberry pi doesn't have built in sound input, the jack is output only. You need a USB sound device for input.

Comment: @Craig, just thought of the same issue. If an USB sound device is used at the Pi, why not just plug that to the Mac and skip the Pi altogether?

Comment: Concerning "many USB Audio interfaces available ... which cost's a lot": but there are also lots of consumer grade products that are quite cheap and work with the Pi. I've got something like the "Terratec Aureon Dual USB" working w/ Archlinux and the Pi. Don't expect studio equipment quality though.

Comment: Everyday USB audio samplers are cheap, high performance ones are not.  But adding a pi to the mix is only likely to make the system noisier, more expensive, and more delicate.

Comment: @Ghanima : Thanks. Any idea about "Terratec Aureon Dual USB" latency?

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with proper jack for your MacBook. You may buy it or do some minimal soldering
See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90344/macbook-pro-mid-2012-microphone-input) thread